# Multilayer CSV to filtered excel

Tags: excel, csv, hierarchical-data, vba

[enter image description here][1]I have the following format CSV Hierarchy data (up to 12 layers) and am trying to fill it in excel so i can at the end create a pivot of data.

Each file (over 1000) are different, i have been trying to code it with Macros but unable to remove all bugs.

First aproach was to create the table and use the above cell on the blanks, but then because of the layers it was not correct by the end of the table

Any idea on how to approach this only by using Macros?

```
Level 1,Level 2,Level 3,Level 4,Level 5,Level 6,Level 7,Level 8,Level 9,Level 10,Level 11,Level 12
Test
,,,,,Components
,,,,,,DEFAULT LOGIC
,,,,,,,z04 - z05
,,,,,,,,z04 ()
,,,,,,,,,%PWR_PG_U_BACKLIGHT% ()
Components
,C
,,C802 - C842
,,,C802
,,,,1 (1)
,,,,2 (2)
```

[This is what i got|https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ2Qg.png]

[This is what i need for the pivot|https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q6jq.png]

Comment: Are you trying to read the data from a CSV file and do a TextToColumns using VBA ?

Comment: the problem with doing that is that i get phased out one cell.
it looks like

`Components    
 C   
  C802 - C842  
   C802
    1 (1)
    2 (2)`

Comment: i cant make it show the structure, but you can get it by doing that into excel and doing the text to columns

Answer (score 1):

to do a 'Text To Columns' in VBA

```
row_count = 13

For i = 1 To row_count
    strArray = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ",")
    For Count = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
        Cells(i, Count + 1).Value = strArray(Count)
    Next
Next i
```

Comment: It does the same as     

`Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True`

the problem is that when pivoted you cannot get the value of cell A1 for lets say a level 12 layer value.

Comment: can you show me the output you are looking for, because i am not able to understand what is that you want

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with the above solution but with slightly changes.
It takes a little time though.

```
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    row_count = Selection.Rows.Count
    col_count = Selection.Columns.Count


For i = 1 To row_count
    strArray = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ",")
    For Count = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
    If strArray(Count) = "" Then
        Cells(i, Count + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    End If
    If strArray(Count) <> "" Then
        Cells(i, Count + 1).Value = strArray(Count)
    End If
    Next
Next i
```

Comment: but, this doesn't have the incremented value like, the value below C802 - C842 should be C802 - C843. and thats what i am trying to do now

Comment: it shouldn't increment any value.
All data is imported from another place and is already there

Comment: it is hierarchical data but in CSV file, that was my problem

Comment: glad to know that you found the required solution

Comment: without your part i wouldn't be able to get it, thanks!